# Passing DataContext in Telerik RadGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radgridview

I use c# .NET 4.5 and WPF RadControls from Telerik.

On my `MainWindow` I have a `RadTabControl` and in my code behind I bind my `MainViewModel` like this:

```
 this.DataContext = new MainViewmodel();
```

The `ItemSource` of the `RadTabControl`  is bound in XAML:

```
 <telerik:RadTabControl ... ItemsSourc={Binding Tabs} .. />
```

I also use a `ContentSelector` to load different Contents to my Tabs. These Contents are `UserControls`. On one `UserControl` I use a `RadGRidView` with it's own `ItemsSource` that I bind in the code behind:

```
TestGridView.ItemsSource = Tasks.GetTasks();
```

The `RadGridView Columns` bound to it's own style:

```
 <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
   <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" Width="*" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle}" />
 </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>

  <Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewCell}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="#f2f2f2" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" Padding="0,5,0,5">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Titel}" />
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Start}" Foreground="#9fa2ae"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text=" XXX - XXX " />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Startzeit}" Foreground="#9fa2ae" />
                                    <telerik:RadButton Height="30" Content="Right Button" Command="{Binding AddTabCommand}" CommandParameter="Tab9999"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The Problem is that the `RadButton` does not fire the `DelegateCommand` of my `MainViewModel`. I have also the same Button in the UserControl out of the `RadGridView`, this works fine.

Please can somebody tell me how I can fix this problem of my `RadButton` in the `RadGridView`?

Thanks a lot
Best Regards
RR

PS: I have a simple project, but can't attach it

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is happening is that the binding on your RadButton is trying to find the AddTabCommand on the DataContext of the button, not the parent Window.

To fix this, I would advise setting the style inside the Window's resources, and instead of using this:

```
Command="{Binding AddTabCommand}"
```

Give the Window a name, and use this:

```
Command="{Binding ElementName=windowName, Path=DataContext.AddTabCommand}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what Mike said its not finding AddTabCommand in your DataContext(ViewModel). 
You can try with specifying whole path of the command :

**Command="{Binding ElementName=windowName, Path=NameSapce_Name.ViewModelName.AddTabCommand}".**